Multiple WebSockets for a single client
This is my first time playing around with this kind of things, so I appreciate any help.
I am trying to write a small web-app that launches commands on a server on demand. For every command that I launch I wanted to create a new tab and have stdout of the command shown there.
My first attempt was something like this:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <div class="container mt-5">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="commandTabs" role="tablist">
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content" id="commandTabContent">
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            let tabCounter = 1;

            // Gets called by pressing a button to launch a script
            function createNewTab(ws_message) {
                // Dynamically create a new tab
                // Each with an InnerElement to show some text (id: outputId)

                tabCounter++;
                openWebSocket(outputId, ws_message);
            }

            function openWebSocket(outputId, ws_message) {
                outputElement = document.getElementById(outputId);
                const ws = new WebSocket("ws://" + window.location.host + "/ws");

                ws.onmessage = function(event) {
                    outputElement.innerText += event.data + '\n';
                };
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>

My idea was to open a websocket for each tab that I create, and then update its text with every message that I receive. The problem that I am having is that all text is only being added to whatever is the last tab I created. Is this because I have my new WebSocket as a local variable inside my openWebSocketFunction, so it just gets overwritten?
How do I overcome this? Should I have like a global vector (or whatever JS equivalent is) of websockets and push them there so each tab keeps its own websocket?
Thanks

Firstly...
const ws = new WebSocket("ws://" + window.location.host + "/ws");

Creating a websocket doesn’t guarantee that the client side has approved/accepted and that you’re all ready to go! :)
You should do some error checking with try{} catch{} because my custom browser for one, would never accept them unless your website is white-listed for communication and/or the user has a membership account there.
But it's not just me... there are many popular-browser extensions out there for catching/blocking websockets so you should start checking that communication has indeed been established and not assume it's a given.
Anyway, aside from that little quirk... let’s move onto the problem at hand.
When you declare...
outputElement = document.getElementById(outputId);

What do you think is gonna happen without specifying which tab you're refering to?
Try something like this instead...
outputElement = Tab_ID.contentWindow.document.getElementById(outputId);

Unless of course I misunderstood what you meant by creating a new "tab”!
I'm assuming a new "tab" is a new window not some kind of container in the same document.

This is what I mean by tabs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/navs-tabs/#javascript-behavior.
My problem is not creating the tabs. That works all fine. My issue is that I (think) I am creating a websocket per tab, but all messages only go through the last websocket I create.

If a “tab” is some kind of container then please edit your question to reflect this so that others won’t get confused like me, because when we talk about tabs and frames we usually mean a new window. ie: Use “container” instead of “tab”.
